# Android: Horizontal Alignment of Switchcompat from both sides

Tags: android, switchcompat

I am trying to align android switchcompat on both side whether its checked or unchecked but without success.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

and here is the result

[image]

Any ideas how to get it done?

Comment: Those look aligned to me. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I am trying to allign start/end of track and thumb on both sides

Answer (score 0):

The Switches (the view bounds of switches to be specific) in your image are aligned as expected. However, it appears as though they are not aligned because the thumb actually goes a little out of the switch track (still within the view bounds). If you want the thumb and track to be aligned on both sides, you can create a custom Switch.

An example would be:

Create background.xml as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable1" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable2"/>
</selector>
```

Set this as background for Switch:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

You will get something like:

[image]

I know this aint perfect in terms of design, but you get the idea!
This shows that the view bounds are actually aligned in both checked and unchecked states.

You can customize it further by setting the track, thumb and so on...

On tweaking the background a little and setting the track you can get something like:

[image]

Cheers!